# 10.6 crashes average of every 12 hours

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, mac-mini, crash

A couple of days ago, my Snow Leopard Mac Mini started to crash an average of once every 12 or so hours. Symptoms include the display being frozen (no changes in response to any keyboard or mouse input), and being completely unresponsive to network connections (ssh etc.; I've turned off the firewall on a NATted network).

What are the logs/diagnostics I should be looking at to figure out why it's crashing?

Comment: Can you post some hardware specs? When did you buy your mini?

Comment: Try going to Console.app and see what logs are there which can help us diagnose your problem.

Comment: Maybe try to remember what new stuff you installed at about the time these crashes started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ssh gets started by lauchd in response to a low-level network filter in the OS - the core of the mac is certainly hung rather than crashing cleanly.

You will of course want to look for crash report logs in the console app - start primarily in the system library (/Library/Logs/CrashReporter) as well as trying to match up the last few thousand lines in system.log going back in time from when you notice the freeze.

Often a periodic process to log a harmless message will help narrow down the time when normal processes no longer function properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should go to Console.app to see the logs (before and after the crash) and try to find a repeating pattern.

Comment: Note do that as an admin user so you see all the logs

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any logs or other information, it sounds a lot like a RAM issue. It not responding to mouse or SSH input are some giveaways to this. I would take your machine to an Apple Store or Apple Authorized Service Provider to have them run a memory test, as well as diagnostics on the rest of the machine.